# How do I fix the irregularity in my mesh after truingulation and deletion of too many vertices?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

Below is my first attempt into sculpting, Its the face of my character. When I was done then it got so heavy with vertices that edit mode got slow; so I pressed x and did a limited dissolve. The shape of the face as a whole is okay but still its very irregular and messy. Please have a look:

This is the front view:

[image]

And this is what has happened on the sides:

[image]

The same goes for the head. Please advise.

Comment: In this case you're better off using sculpting with Dyntopo enabled on the areas with too few and distorted faces, then use Smooth brush to smooth area a bit, because base topology is already quite messy so you might not worry about it. If you need the model somewhere else like rendering etc. then you'll create its copy with good topology (process of retopology) but only once you finished sculpting